# express cannot handle file extensions in URL

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, vue-router, webpack-dev-middleware

I am using express with webpack-dev-middleware and webpack-hot-middleware in my development environment. I build a storage/DFS module that works in a similar way as GitHub. You paste a URL and it opens up a folder or a file. The problem now that I have is, when I paste a URL that contains a file extension at the end as in (/storage/folder1/folder2/file.py) I get 'Cannot GET /storage/folder1/folder2/file.py'.

It is a VUE app and for routing I am using vue-router. The path configured in VUE app is:

```
path: 'storage/*'
```

Using as a template for VUE app: https://admin.vuebulma.com/#/

Any suggestions on how fix this?

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: My browser opens a web page saying 'Cannot GET /storage/folder1/folder2/file.py'.

Comment: I am having the same issue.  Did you manage to resolve it?